How to prevent bash to interpret this command as a single argument?
Using bash 4.4 (Git Bash on Windows), I want to display a dynamic amount of characters in the console, using printf.
Manually giving this command in the terminal works as expected:
$ set -x;printf '%0.1s' -{1..44}
+ printf %0.1s -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -19 -20 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -26 -27 -28 -29 -30 -31 -32 -33 -34 -35 -36 -37 -38 -39 -40 -41 -42 -43 -44

The -{1..44} expands correctly and the number of dashes displayed in the term is correct.
However, in a script, using a variable, expansion is not as I expected it to be, and I do not know how to tell bash to interpret correctly:
_calculated_progress=44
printf '%0.1s' -{1..$_calculated_progress}

+ printf %0.1s '-{1..44}'

As you can see above, the argument seems to be interpreted as a single argument and expansion (if the term is correct) does not occur like it did in the first example.
Using a variable, how may I make it so that arguments are correctly passed to printf and 44 dashes are displayed in the console?

i=0; while [ "$i" -lt "$progress" ]; do printf -; i=$((i+1)); done

@knittl That indead is a solution. But isn't there a solution directly with printf to avoid the loop ?

I don't think there is, unless you go for eval (which has its own share of caveats)

x=44; printf '%*s' $x | tr ' ' -?

See "Brace expansion with variable?" and "How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?"
